# How can I get my button to play the sound I have loaded in sound pool?

Tags: android, button, audio, soundpool

I guess I need an onClickListener for the button to work but how do I add an onClickListener to this code so that my button will play the sound that I have loaded? At the moment it says my method PlaySound1 is never used.

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        Clubb1 = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 1);
        clubb1Id = Clubb1.load(getActivity(), R.raw.clubb1,1);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one_layout, container, false);


    }

public void playSound1(View view)
{Clubb1.play(clubb1Id,1,1,1,0,1);}


        }
```

This is the .xml file linked to the above .java file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#F20C36"
     >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Clubb 1"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginTop="61dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="43dp"
        android:onClick="playSound1"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

At the moment it says it cannot resolve symbol 'Playsound1'. When I run the emulator and click the button the app crashes, so the sound is not played. How do I link the sound to the button so it can play? Am new to coding.

Comment: Take the argument out of your definition of `playSound1(View view)` and see if it works. If it does it was looking for the method `playSound1()`, when what you had defined was `playSound1(View view)`. I also hope it says it cannot resolve `playSound1` and not `PlaySound1` as you said in your question—or else you're not referring to the correct method—as java is case sensitive.

Comment: So I should have this code? `public void playSound1()
{Clubb1.play(clubb1Id,1,1,1,0,1);}` if so it still comes up saying "method playSound1() is never used" and "cannot resolve symbol playSound1" on the .xml file.

Comment: Add it in java then, I haven't had success with the XML approach in the past. In java you would `Button yourButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);`, then `yourButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {...});`